# Route table issue in MVC 3/4/5 application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Lets say we have two controller HomeController and DocumentController and 
there is a "Index" action method in HomeController and "Add" action method in DocumentController.

In register route(global.asax) there is a entry of home/index.

But when I try to access Document/Add It doesn't throw any page not found error.
Ideally it should, as there is no entry for route "Document/Add" in register route in global asax.

How come this happens ?

**HomeController:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

**DocumentController :**

```
public class DocumentController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

**RouteConfig:**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =        UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: To reproduce this, we need both Controller declarations with the action methods involved, as well as what your route table looks like (the RouteTables.config file).

Comment: Post your route config.  It sounds like it is hitting the default route provided by the framework (matching {controller}/{action}).

Comment: yep, after you posted your code, you have confirmed there is no issue.  You are describing the behavior that the `Default` route is designed for.

Comment: Put another way, the "home/index" path is just the default when the request does not include a controller and/or action. So `http://foo.com`, `http://foo.com/home`, and `http://foo.com/home/index` all end up in your `HomeController`'s `Index` method. It doesn't mean it won't resolve other paths.

Comment: I understand your point, but my question is How MVC resolves/call Document/add url when there is no entry for it in RouteConfig. How MVC add Document/Add in route table.

Answer (score 0):

If you had

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =        UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Then yes there would be no route the defaults are for when you just have {baseurl}/

But as I understand it your route has a wildcard controller which is correctly resolving

Have a look at http://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/

@CraigW summed it up well in his comment.